# How to do collision in MonoGame properly?

Tags: c#, game-physics, game-development, collision, monogame

I've been making a game using MonoGame framework, but I came across a problem when I tried to handle collisions, to be more specific, player collisions.

I tried to search some things on YouTube and google and stuff, but I was not satisficed with any of those tutorials. I want the player to stop moving when he encounters a collision, however, if I just use (Rectangle) Bounds.Intersects(), then the player stops, but I can't move him back neither. I kind of edited it (following the things I've found on the internet), but now I was facing another issue - somehow when I collided from a side, it runs also stops the movement in Up/Down direction (and for some reason just in one of them) or vise versa. What I tried as a last thing is that I tried to make an array of all positions that player cannot go into, and that kind of worked, however, the collision was not precise as it should be and rather it seemed like a circle with radius of the sprite height that has center in bottom right corner, which is weird and not expected. I'd be really grateful if someone would tell me about a way to handle collisions in the way I wish to do so.

```
       public void Update(GraphicsDeviceManager gm, GameTime gt)
        {
            Move(gm, gt);

            AvoidCoveredPositions();

            coveredPositions.Clear();
            UpdateCoveredPositions();

            if (!isFacingLeft)
            {
                flipSprite = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
            }
            else
            {
                flipSprite = SpriteEffects.None;
            }

            position += entity._direction;

            entity.Update(playerSprite, position);
        }      


        private void AvoidCoveredPositions()
        {
            foreach (Vector2 coveredPos in Enemy.GetCoveredPositions())
            {
                if (Vector2.Distance(position, coveredPos) < playerSprite.Width)
                {
                    Vector2 moveDirection = Vector2.Normalize(position - coveredPos);
                    position += moveDirection * speed;
                }
            }
        }

        private void UpdateCoveredPositions()
        {
            Rectangle spriteBounds = new Rectangle(
                (int)position.X,
                (int)position.Y,
                playerSprite.Width,
                playerSprite.Height
            );

            for (int x = spriteBounds.Left; x <= spriteBounds.Right; x++)
            {
                for (int y = spriteBounds.Top; y <= spriteBounds.Bottom; y++)
                {
                    if (x == spriteBounds.Left || x == spriteBounds.Right || y == spriteBounds.Top || y == spriteBounds.Bottom)
                    {
                        coveredPositions.Add(new Vector2(x, y));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public static List<Vector2> GetCoveredPositions()
        {
            return coveredPositions;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved it.
            Vector2 newPosition = _position + _direction;


            foreach (GameObject go in GM.Objects)
            {
                if (go == this)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (Bounds.Intersects(go.Bounds))
                {
                    break;
                } else
                {
                    _position = newPosition;
                }
            }